# Finish XmlHttpRequest (XHR) Even When User Leaves Webpage/site

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, amplifyjs

**Background:**

Website using amplifyjs for ajax calls.

**Problem:**

User makes a selection, but leaves webpage/site before the xhr completes.  Their selection is not saved.

**Expected Result**

The service that is being called is a void service, so it will not be returning anyways.  The expected result would be that once a user has made their selection, and the ajax call is made, the user can do whatever they want (go to another page, close the browser, etc.) and their selection will still be saved.

**Question**

What causes this to occur? Is there a way ensure that the XHR completes regardless?